# Python: extending array keeps square bracket

Tags: python

I am trying to extend a list to add additional values but in the results it keeps displaying the end of the previous list.

```
def landmarksPoint():
    landmarkPoints = []

    # Check for range of landmarks (0 to 23) within the image, if all are displayed then continue to save the file.
    for n in range(pointNumber):
        # Split each line and column to save to text file and save to landmarkPoints Array.
        x = landmarks.part(n).x
        y = landmarks.part(n).y
        # Print each line for testing and append it to array.
        print("x:", x, " y:", y)
        landmarkPoints.append((x, y))

    return landmarkPoints


for hand in hands:
        landmarks = predictor(imageGray1, composite1)
        points1.append(landmarksPoint())
        print(points1)

boundaryLoc = (1,1), (700,1), (1590, 1), (1590,500), (1590, 1190), (700, 1190), (1, 1190), (1,500)

points1.extend(boundaryLoc)
print(points1)



  OUTPUT: 
[[(992, 191), (1178, 337), (895, 702), (859, 873), (831, 991), (836, 514), (794, 627), (762, 768), (744, 900), (770, 396), (728, 479), (705, 586), (1213, 458), (690, 703), (773, 229), (803, 140), (1228, 147), (1281, 543), (1082, 471), (1027, 576), (996, 712), (970, 841), (933, 966), (922, 563)], (1, 1), (700, 1), (1590, 1), (1590, 500), (1590, 1190), (700, 1190), (1, 1190), (1, 500)]
```

Comment: You appear to have some indentation issues.

Comment: Sorry! I messed up when adding it into the stack overflow! I'll fix this now!

Comment: What is your _expected_ output?

Comment: [[(992, 191), (1178, 337), (895, 702), (859, 873), (831, 991), (836, 514), (794, 627), (762, 768), (744, 900), (770, 396), (728, 479), (705, 586), (1213, 458), (690, 703), (773, 229), (803, 140), (1228, 147), (1281, 543), (1082, 471), (1027, 576), (996, 712), (970, 841), (933, 966), (922, 563), (1, 1), (700, 1), (1590, 1), (1590, 500), (1590, 1190), (700, 1190), (1, 1190), (1, 500)]]

But as you can see, it puts a square bracket, splitting up the two lists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) say that `list.extend()` extends the calling object with the contents of an argument that is an iterable.

So, `points1.extend(boundaryLoc)` extends the list `points1` using the contents of the tuple `boundaryLoc` (you can verify that `boundaryLoc` is a tuple of tuples by examining the result of `type(boundaryLoc)`).

This means that each tuple contained within `boundaryLoc` will in effect be appended to `points1`, which is exactly what your output shows.

If you want to append a list of tuples to `points1`, you can do this:

```py
boundaryLoc = [(1,1), (700,1), (1590, 1), (1590,500), (1590, 1190), (700, 1190), (1, 1190), (1,500)]
points1.append(boundaryLoc)
```

Note that we have explicitly made `boundaryLoc` a list (not a tuple) of tuples, and we use `append()` instead of `extend()`.

If you really wanted to use `extend()`, you could do this:

```py
points1.extend([boundaryLoc])
```